# How do I change text button ripple effect or How can I completely remove it in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]

this is a text button inside a sized when ever I press the button I have this blue effect I want it change it to yellow color or remove it completely

```
SizedBox(
  width: 145,
  height: 146,
  child: TextButton(
    child: const Text('Mentor'),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
```

Answer (score 4):

**You can fix splash like below code:**

```
SizedBox(
    width: 145,
    height: 146,
    child: TextButton(
        style: const ButtonStyle(
            splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
        ),
        child: const Text('Mentor'),
        onPressed: () {},
    ),
),
```